# Scala groupby Tuples

Tags: scala

I have a Seq[((Tuple A),(Tuple B))]

Is there an easy way to groupby Tuple A so I get Seq[(Tuple A, Seq[Tuple B])]

I.ve tried groupby(x => x.TupleA) but it throws a Mapping Exception: Do not know how to serialize key of tuple.

Comment: Can you give an example of your Seq?

Comment: [((1,2,3)(4,5,6)), ((1,2,3)(5,6,7)), ((2,3,4)(4,5,6))]

Comment: I want [((1,2,3),[(4,5,6),(5,6,7)]), ((2,3,4),[(4,5,6)])]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this works. Use `groupBy(_._1)` to group your sequence by the first element of the tuple, and collect the second element of the tuples in a list:

```
val s = Seq(((1,2,3), (4,5,6)), ((1,2,3), (5,6,7)), ((2,3,4), (4,5,6)))

s.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
// res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[(Int, Int, Int),Seq[(Int, Int, Int)]] = 
//          Map((1,2,3) -> List((4,5,6), (5,6,7)), (2,3,4) -> List((4,5,6)))
```

If you want the result to be a list instead of Map, use `toList` to convert:

```
s.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2)).toList
```

gives:

```
// List(((1,2,3),List((4,5,6), (5,6,7))), ((2,3,4),List((4,5,6))))
```